# Why compiled code creates corrupted file in windows in linux works fine

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, copy

The following code, compiled with gcc.exe from MinGW-w64 (i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0) under windows using gcc -o copy.exe copy.c creates garbage files when used to copy a file; with either to many or far too little bytes copied. Under Linux with gcc it works fine (source and destination have identical md5, text files, binary files, doesn't matter)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *fpo = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    int SIZE = 1000000;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    size_t bytes;
    while (0 < (bytes = fread(buffer, 1, SIZE, fp)))
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, fpo);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpo);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: So why do you use *binary mode* to read, but not to write? On windows, this mode is **indeed** different from text mode. (as line endings on windows are `\r\n`, this is translated to a single `\n` when reading and translated back to `\r\n` when writing in *text mode*)

Comment: Minor: like better performance with `SIZE` as a power-of-2 like 65536.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you read in binary data, but then you attempt to write that data out as text, as indicated in the modes you chose to do this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
FILE *fpo = fopen(argv[2], "w");
```

This will cause issues on Windows and potentially other OSs, because line endings are handled differently by different standard libraries. Windows uses `\r\n` as a line ending, which is converted to `\n` when read in from a *text* file, whereas under Linux the line ending is `\n`, which needs no conversion to `\n`. When writing a *text* file, Windows converts `\n` to `\r\n`, whereas Linux needs no conversion for its line endings.

Changing the second line to

```
FILE *fpo = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
```

should fix your issues.

Comment: This indeed fixes the issue. Why would anybody use text mode for reading/writing files if it acts differently on different platforms?

Comment: @Niels _Because_ it acts differently on different platforms. When writing a text file it might be convenient to have correct line endings without having to care about the platform your code runs.

Comment: @Niels When a C program writes a `'\n'`, in text mode it's translated to the underlying OS's end-of-line representation.  When a C program reads in text mode, the OS's end-of-line is similarly translated, and the program sees a single `'\n'`.  If you don't want those translations, that's what binary mode is for.